# When creating an anonymous class must I include the methods of the extended class regardless if abstract or concrete?

Tags: java, oop

When we use this `new A() {};`, if A is concrete and not abstract, do we have to include the methods of A? What if A was an interface? Do we have to include the methods of A? Why?

Answer (score -1):

Whether a class is anonymous has nothing to do with whether you must include the methods of the extended class or of the implemented interface.

If `A` is concrete, then you don't have to override any methods.  You can override them of course, and you should override at least one of them, or else having an anonymous subclass is useless; you could use `A` directly.  You can supply your own new methods, although they won't be callable directly.

If `A` is abstract or an interface, then you must override all abstract methods, just as with any other named concrete class.

One should use the `@Override` annotation on all methods intended to override a superclass or implement an interface, to ensure that typos don't result in a method that doesn't override anything.